# Laravel: orWhereHas() doesn't respect where()

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent

```
$q = $request->query('q');

$faktur = FakturKonsinyasi::with(['indukbuku', 'distributor'])
  ->where('qty', '<>', 0)
  ->where('id_faktur_konsinyasi', 'like', '%' . $q . '%')
  ->where('id_faktur_konsinyasi', 'like', 'FKTKNST%')
  ->orderBy('id_faktur_konsinyasi', 'ASC');

if(!str_contains($q,'FKTKNST') && !empty($q)) {
      $faktur = $faktur->whereHas('indukbuku', function ($query) use ($q) {
      $query->where('judul_buku',  'like', '%' . $q . '%');
    })->orWhereHas('distributor', function ($query) use ($q) {
      $query->where('nm_distributor',  'like', '%' . $q . '%');
    });
}

$faktur = $faktur->paginate(10);
```

The above code didn't work. I want to filter $faktur by id_faktur_konsinyasi with id starting from "FKTKNST", it works if it only has two condition for the id_faktur_konsinyasi. But, when those two whereHas added, everything in the where outside condition block is ignored.

Browsing, AI included of course, none of their result works.

Answer (score 0):

this is happening cause you are mixing "and" and "or" conditions.

try to isolate them...

```
$q = $request->query('q');

$faktur = FakturKonsinyasi::with(['indukbuku', 'distributor'])
    ->where('qty', '<>', 0)
    ->where('id_faktur_konsinyasi', 'like', '%' . $q . '%')
    ->where('id_faktur_konsinyasi', 'like', 'FKTKNST%')
    ->orderBy('id_faktur_konsinyasi', 'ASC');

if(!str_contains($q,'FKTKNST') && !empty($q)) {
    $faktur->where(function ($builder) use ($q) {
        $builder->whereHas('indukbuku', function ($query) use ($q) {
            $query->where('judul_buku',  'like', '%' . $q . '%');
        })->orWhereHas('distributor', function ($query) use ($q) {
            $query->where('nm_distributor',  'like', '%' . $q . '%');
        });
    });
}

$faktur = $faktur->paginate(10);
```

Comment: nope, doesn't work. even converting it to raw (with bindings ofc)